# Removing orphaned sidecar files by extension

Tags: bash

In a folder I might have the following types of filenames:

```
filename.imageExtension
filename.imageExtension.sidecarExtension
filename.sidecarExtension
```

The extensions are as follows:

imageExtension can be a number of extensions like: `.nef`, `.raf`, `.orf`, etc.

sidecarExtension can be a few extensions like:  `.xmp`, `.pts`, `.pp3`, etc.

So in a folder I could, for example, have files like:

```
tree.nef
tree.nef.pp3

car.raf
car.xmp
car.raf.pp3

house.xmp
something.nef.pp3
```

In this case `house.xmp` and `something.nef.pp3` are orphaned files **that should be removed**. *What determines that those files are orphaned, is that there is no corresponding image file* (a file with the same name but with an imageExtension and no sidecarExtension).

Is there a way to remove all the orphaned files, and only the orphaned files with a bash script?

I have been trying to do it with nested for loops and if statements like:

```
if [[ -e $(echo "$filename" | sed "s/"$imageExtension"/"$sidecarExtension"/g" ) ]]
```

or

```
if [[ -e $(echo "$filename" | sed "s/"$imageExtension""$sidecarExtension"/"$sidecarExtension"/g" ) ]]
```

but I never got the results I need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one possible solution:

```
shopt -s nullglob extglob;

# Get all sidecar files
for file in *.{xmp,pts,pp3}
do
  # Generate all permutations of filenames that it may belong to,
  # and let globbing delete the ones that don't exist
  candidates=("${file%.*}"@() "${file%.*}".{nef,raf,orf}@()); 

  # If none exist, the file can be deleted
  [[ ${#candidates[@]} -eq 0 ]] && echo rm "$file"
done
```

It relies on the fact that with nullglob and extglob, `"file"@()` will expand into `file` if the file exists, or nothing if it does not.

If it's not obvious, the `echo` must be removed to actually perform the deletion. Otherwise, it'll do a dry run and just say which files it would have deleted.

Comment: This works nicely. Is there a way to substitute `{xmp,pts, pp3}` and `{nef,raf,orf}` with lists? Something like `sidecar=(xmp,pts,pp3) image=(nef,raf,orf)`. There are a lot of image formats and I would like to put them in a list at the beginning of the script. @that-other-guy

Comment: `@()` is a nice trick! I probably misunderstood the question but could you please explain to me what is the purpose of the first `"${file%.*}"@()`? Thanks :)

Comment: @PesaThe So foo.bar.pp3 will be considered non-orphaned if foo.bar exists (instead of foo.bar.nef). In this case it doesn't check the extension.

Comment: @vato Not directly, no. It could be rewritten using nested loops

Comment: How can we keep the xmp with a version number added to file name (in the form "_nn" where nn is two-digit)? I mean if there is pic1.nef, pic1.nef.xmp, and pic1_01.nef.xmp, I'd like to keep the last one too. Those xmp are created by programs such as darktable when we process different versions of the same initial raw file for example.

Answer (score 1):

This was a nice solution, thanks, it worked well. I did find it was slow, so I delved into how the script works. I think that the extglob and nullglob testing may be a bit overkill and what was slowing it down. I decided to try and write it using more traditional bash methods... and I think this works just as well? It's a slight variation for my needs, but I think you could easily update it for other sidecar files.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

# Get all sidecar files
for file in *.pp3
do
  base="${file%.*}"  # could be .pp3 instead of .*, 
                     # but .* is future proof to diff extensions
  if [ -e $base ]; then
     echo -n . #checked and kept
  else
     rm "$file" && echo -en "\ndeleted $file"
  fi
done
echo "\ndone!"
```